# Can I use CSS to align a <div> within a <td>?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, alignment

I have some complicated tabular data.  In each `<td>`, I have two closely related kinds of data that I would like to be visually separated, like this:

```
<td>
    <div class='float'>
        <ul class='group1'>
            <li>Item 1</li>       
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='sink'>
        <ul class='group2'>
            <li>item 1</li>       
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

Because these lists are closely related, I'd like to keep them in one table cell.  (Adding an additional row for group2 would also require a significant rewrite of the PHP generating the table.)  What I'm wanting to do is to have div.float aligned with the top of the TD, and div.sink aligned with the bottom.  I feel like this should be doable in CSS, but vigorous Googling has availed me not at all. I'm already using jQuery (and jQueryUI), so if there's a jQuery way to do this that would work too.

Halp?

ETA: You can see the table in action in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mysphyt/JVdDA/ .  The button below the table approximates the desired behavior with jQuery, but this feels like a deeply hinky solution, and I'd definitely prefer to go with a pure CSS fix.  Desired behavior: div.float on top of the TD, div.sink on bottom.  (Meaning: tutors at the top of the TD, and the divs for faculty and staff aligned with each other on the bottom.)  I feel like I'm not much clarifying with my words, so hopefully the fiddle will make clear what I mean.

Comment: You want the first `ul` to take the top half, and the second to take the bottom half? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: How is it lining up now? Is there another column that is making the cell grow bigger than the two divs?

Comment: @mysphyt: http://jsfiddle.net/5r5KH/ - is that an accurate representation of your problem? And you'd just like `float` and `sink` to be at the top and bottom of their containing `td`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your not wrapping your classes within double quotes?

Comment: @SirB It's a bad habit.  The backend is in PHP, and in PHP `echo "<div class='$className'>"` is much easier than `echo "<div class=\"$classname\">"` or similar.  (Double quotes are needed in the PHP string for variable expansion.)

Comment: @msphyt I kind of figured you were using another language. Just wanted to make sure your HTML syntax was correct and maybe that was why your div wasn't aligning, nevermind then.

Comment: @thirtydot Yup, that's about it.  I added a fiddle in the OP with the table in question.

Comment: DIVs and tables don't normally play well together. You'll either have a hacky Javascript fix, or a hacky CSS fix. Although the road seems painful, it'll probably make more sense to rewrite your table structure so things can align better. If your using tables, stick to tables, if your using DIVs, stick with divs (unless its a table IN a div, that's a different story).

Comment: Are there any known heights for the nested list?

Answer (score 1):

What about going oldschool. This will avoid the two uls sitting on top of one another:

```
<td>
<table width="100%" height="100%">
    <tr><td valign="top">
        <ul class='group1'>
            <li>Item 1</li>       
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td valign="bottom">
        <ul class='group2'>
            <li>item 1</li>       
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </td></tr>
</table>
</td>
```

The inside table will ajust to the surrounding td and and make the surrounding td bigger if the content of the ul is to big.

Comment: I do not consider tables within tables to be a good practice.

Comment: I respect your practice. I also try hard to go new-school. But I think vertical alignment with divs and CSS sometime is very hard and time-consuming. Working with CSS positioning and percentage has often given me trouble too. I'm sure you can define the width, height, alignment etc in CSS to make it even more W3C-friendly. I just hope new standards eventually will deal with this in a better and easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp:

```
.float { vertical-align: top; }
.sink { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

If this doesn't help, please post a jsFiddle of the list and any existing CSS :)

Comment: A link to the real W3 would be better: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align but you'd still be applying `vertical-align` to the wrong thing.

Comment: As far as I know, `vertical-align` is for inline elements only. So this definitely wont work...

Comment: @Midas - `vertical-align` works differently for table cells compared to all other elements. It basically emulates the old-school `valign` attribute on a `<td>`. It's one of the more inelegant parts of the CSS spec.  :-/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct what do You want to do is that if, for example, You have td with height 500px and div.float height on 100px, div.sink height on 100px then You don't want that bottom edge of div.float is top edge of div.sink? Top edge of div.float should be top edge of td, bottom edge of div.sink should be bottom edge of td? Then I think that You can do that by position: absolute.

```
<td>
    <div class="class_name"> <!-- added -->
     <div class='float'>
        <ul class='group1'>
            <li>Item 1</li>       
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class='sink'>
        <ul class='group2'>
            <li>item 1</li>       
            <li>item 2</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div> <!-- added -->
</td>
```

css:

```
.class_name {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;  /*added*/
}

.sink {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

But I'm not sure if that will be working. I used something similar in past and if I remember correctly then it can be helpful. :) Try it out and share if that worked.

EDIT: Insert these two divs in another div like I edited above. Modifie also css. I've just tested it and it works. :)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately.  The effect of this appears to be that the divs are no longer used in calculating the height of the table cells, so there is a table with tiny cells and the divs sitting happily on top of it and one another.

Comment: Try now with edited code. Here it is in action: [http://jsfiddle.net/xP2jk/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xP2jk/2/) I added there some extra styles to show it. You need only that what is in my answer here.

Comment: Part of the problem, though, is that the content is dynamically generated, so I can't set a height manually.  If you get rid of the height: 500px line, things fall apart: http://jsfiddle.net/xP2jk/3/ .  Thanks for the help, though. :)

Comment: Do You know min-height's of these 2 divs? If yes then You can try set min-height to .class_name div (here [http://jsfiddle.net/xP2jk/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/xP2jk/9/) its .first).

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the CSS you need to .float and .sink. No need to wrap them in a div. We call this Divitis, and considering that as 'new school' hasn't been accurate since early 2000's.

Answer (score 0):

Have to agree with previous comments.  If you are stuck using tables then stick with tables and in that case using rowspan...http://jsfiddle.net/cssguru/5r5KH/4/

Answer (score 0):

First add the required height to your row then

add the following style. It should also work if the height of row is not mentioned.

But its safe to add some height for the row.

```
.float
{
      position: absolute;
}

.sink
{
     position: absolute;
     margin-top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's my thoughts:

- This table is massive. You should seriously consider removing some information from the cells or displaying it in some other way
- Adding additional rows in the "original" table will most likely make things a lot worse in terms of content-representation => the additional data is directly related to the first div (don't even think about row-/colspan)
- Same goes for sub-tables. Though I think it would work without JavaScript. (Just make the sub-table 100% height, then "valign" the top row top, the bottom row bottom)

Here's my solution:

- You will need JavaScript. There are solutions for pure CSS equal height columns, but they don't work when those are inside different table cells -- or I don't know how that would work
- What you want to do is make the upper part equal height
- This requires the "upper part" to always exist
- You will also want to change the valign property to "top"

Here's a fiddle of how this could work (I fork'd yours) http://jsfiddle.net/3NzQ4/1/